# How can I display the related posts (by category) at the bottom of each post?

Tags: entries, categories, relations

I'm converting a WordPress blog to Craft - first time playing with categories in Craft, so how can I display the related posts (by category) at the bottom of each post?

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished using Craft's [Relations](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations).

*My example code assumes you know the blog categories slug, and that you are pulling posts from a single category.*

First, you'll have to get a reference to the [category ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.categories) object pointing to the category of the blog post.

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug('your-category-slug').first() %}
```

With a reference to the category model, you'll be able to find related entries.

```
{% for post in craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo({targetElement: category}) %}
    {% if post.id != entry.id %}
        <div class="related-entry">
            <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
            {{ post.body }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The if statement makes sure you aren't including the current post with the related posts.

Comment: It is also probably worth throwing an if statement in the loop so you don't display the original entry as a related entry.

Comment: Yeah, great call. I included that in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done quite easily as follows, assuming that you are on an entry page so `entry` is a variable in your template and your category field is called `categories`.

```twig
{% for relatedEntry in craft.entries({
    section: 'blog',
    relatedTo: entry.categories,
    id: 'not ' ~ entry.id
}) %}
    <a href="{{ relatedEntry.url }}">{{ relatedEntry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I am passing an object into the ElementCriteriaModel for clarity above but you could just as easily do it by chaining parameters onto the ElementCriteriaModel as follows, it's just a matter of preference.

```twig
{% for relatedEntry in craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo(entry.categories).id('not ' ~ entry.id) %}
    <a href="{{ relatedEntry.url }}">{{ relatedEntry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

See [the relatedTo param](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) in the docs to understand the magic.

Comment: Thanks guys! :) Would be awesome and very useful if someone could add the categories & tags templates on the Craft demo site github.com/pixelandtonic/ontherocks ;)

Comment: @lucassoares Sounds like somebody's got a great idea for a pull request! And by somebody, I mean you. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
{% set category = craft.categories.group('{{ entry.topic }}').first() %}`enter code here`
```

For anyone else who stumbles on this post, I wasn't able to get the code working until I changed a few things.

Instead of categories.*slug*, I used category.*group* and made 'your category-slug' {{ entry.topic }}, topic being how I assign my *single* category to entries.

Comment: Passing a string `'{{ entry.topic }}'` to the param works for you? Doesn't sound right...

Comment: topic is how I call the single category name that I've assigned to my entries.